# Design pattern and OOP in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I've been working with PHP and few more OOP languages and still wondering about the meaning of design pattern and OOP in PHP and similar languages.

I have some modules in my project: news , forum...
Each module can be access by calling it main class.

- The main class routes the page ~> point to news/article ,
  news/categories.
- Have some module settings / variables.

And the child classes in each module handle those specific features / pages.

What's the best design pattern for this model? Create instance of the class or it's child?

Now, i initialize a class, and access to the child class static methods like the example bellow. But i've read using static method can slow down the code?

```
class news {
  __construct() {
     // define module settings
     ...
     // routing all module pages
     categories::list();
  }
  function modulesetting() {}
}
class categories extends news {
  static function list() {}
}
```

Comment: using static method is little bit slower than instance of class but on the other hand static method save memory. i see your child class `categories` inherit class `news` so you don't need instance of class `news` because instance of `categories` inherit method construct etc..

Comment: you could overwrite method `list` and `modulesetting` for each child class, there is ways to call parent methods from overwriten methods like `parent::list();` or `parent::modulesettings();` and one more think is you could for example do something like this in `news->__construct`: `if($this instanceof categories){ ... }`

Comment: if you create abstract base class for all main classes which handle routing and add fundamental control for all childrens its best way in my opinion

Comment: @Kazz I thought about this solution: call to the child method directly avoid creating `news` instance. However i don't want to put so much code on the `index` file, categories in one of many child classes. I want `index` file to contact with each module by only one file, news instance for news module, forum instance for forum module and routing job belongs to each module ... If do on your way, i have change routing to the `index` file. What should be the best solution here?

Comment: create your `__autoload` function put it into separate file like `autoload.php`, then in each file who need access to these classes include `autoload.php`, use namespaces for each class and based on namespace create folder structure

Comment: create one routing class for index, which select which module will be used then create instance of module call method for handle routing on this module and thats it

Comment: @Kazz I've found the easier way for doing this: I call to the child class directly, in the `__construct` of `categories` class, i use `parent::__construct();` to call to the `news` constructor, so i'll have routing, permission to access every setting,variables defined in the parent class

Answer (score 0):

Just for show what i mean (take it easy):

Folder structure:

```
/index.php
/autoload.php
/IModule.php
/IPage.php
/BaseModule.php
/modules/
/modules/News.php
/modules/News/
/modules/News/Categories.php
/modules/News/Acticle.php
...
```

index.php

```
require_once('./autoload.php');

// based on request select which module to use
$moduleName = 'News';
$page = ('module\\'.$moduleName)::route();
$page->render();
```

autoload.php

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    $filename = __DIR__ . '/'. $classname . '.php';
    include_once($filename);
}
```

IModule.php

```
interface IModule {
    public static function route();
    //protected function moduleSettings();
}
```

IPage.php

```
interface IPage {
    public function render();
}
```

BaseModule.php

```
abstract class BaseModule implements \IModule {
    // fundamental stuff
}
```

News.php

```
namespace modules;

class News extends \BaseModule {
    protected $someProperty;

    __construct() {
       // define module settings
    }

    public static function route(){
        // routing all module pages, based on request        
        $page = 'modules\News\Categories';
        return new $page;
    }

    protected function moduleSettings(){ ... }
}
```

Categories.php

```
namespace modules\News;

class Categories extends \module\News implements \IPage {

    public function render() {
        /* access to module news */
        $this->someProperty;
        $this->moduleSettings(); /* or if method moduleSettings is overwriten then */ parent::moduleSettings();
        /* for example */  
        echo '<html></html>';
    }

}
```